# unable to add data to firebase from my server using java

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying following code to send data from my server to firebase in java :

```
public class FirebaseManager {
    public void configFirebase() throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("entered");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("/home/avy/Documents/avy-7ad6df4da352.json"))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://avy.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp firebaseApp =  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog");

        DatabaseReference postsRef = reference.child("posts");

        DatabaseReference newPostRef = postsRef.push();
        Task t = newPostRef.setValue(new Post("avy", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"));
System.out.println(t.isComplete());
        postsRef.push().setValue(new Post("sam", "The Turing Machine"));
    }

    public static class Post {

        public String author;
        public String title;

        public Post(String author, String title) {
            this.author=author;
            this.title=title;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            new FirebaseManager().configFirebase();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File Not Found : /home/avy/Documents/avy-7ad6df4da352.json " );
        }
    }

}
```

But following code gives me false.

```
Task t = newPostRef.setValue(new Post("avy", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"));
System.out.println(t.isComplete());
```

Please help me to find the issues in this code.
i want to access firebase database to store my posts , so that it can be delivered further to mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks are asynchronous objects so running line after line your second line of code might run before the task is completed. Did you check the database to see if the post was added ?

If so you can use the onCompleteListener of the class Task to know when it gets completed

Comment: I had trried this : ` t.addOnCompleteListener(new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable command) {
                System.out.println("executing ...");
            }
        }, new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                System.out.println(t.isComplete());
            }
        }); ' onComplete event doesnt execute anyway